I have empty data in request in telegram-app
I have a problem: when I submit a form in a Telegram mini-application on my computer, everything works fine, but when I submit the same form on a mobile device, the GET method is used, and the request becomes empty. Can you help?
<form action="{{$route}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method($method)
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon-container" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67C162.733 515.444 142.37 515.443 132.834 501.67zM192 272c44.183 0 80-35.817 80-80s-35.817-80-80-80-80 35.817-80 80 35.817 80 80 80z"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="location-input" placeholder="Добавить город" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div id="suggestions-container" class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="display: none;"></div>

    <div id="selected-locations" class="selected-locations" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        @foreach($selectedCities as $city)
            <div class="selected-location">{{ $city }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="job_type">Выберите вакансии</label>
        <select id="job_type" name="job_type[]" class="form-control" multiple>
            @foreach($types as $type)
                <option value="{{ $type->id }}"
                        @if(in_array($type->id, $selectedCategories)) selected @endif>
                    {{ $type->name }}
                </option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="locations" name="locations" value="{{ implode(', ', $selectedCities) }}">

    <div id="selected-job-types" class="selected-locations" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>

    <div class="form-group center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Применить</button>
    </div>
</form>


It's pretty much straightforward, the issue is how Telegram handles form submission. By default, Telegram uses the GET method to submit forms, that is why your request is empty.
To handle this issue, try adding 'data-telegram-submit' attr to your form and set the value to 'post'
something like this
<form action="{{$route}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-telegram-submit="post">

<!--- Your form fields --->

</form>

